# How to get size(byte) from ImageView using Picasso Library?

Tags: android, picasso

```
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(selectedImageUri)
                        .resize(1200, 500)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
                                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        int pixels = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth();
                        Log.i("BITMAP PIXELS", "height:"+bitmap.getHeight()+", width:"+bitmap.getWidth());
                        int bytesPerPixel = 0;
                        switch(bitmap.getConfig()) {
                            case ARGB_8888:
                                bytesPerPixel = 4;
                                Log.i("BITMAP CONFIG", "ARGB_8888");
                                break;
                            case RGB_565:
                                bytesPerPixel = 2;
                                Log.i("BITMAP CONFIG", "RGB_565");
                                break;
                            case ARGB_4444:
                                bytesPerPixel = 2;
                                Log.i("BITMAP CONFIG", "ARGB_4444");
                                break;
                            case ALPHA_8 :
                                bytesPerPixel = 1;
                                Log.i("BITMAP CONFIG", "ALPHA_8");
                                break;
                        }
                        int byteCount = pixels * bytesPerPixel;
                                Log.i("BITMAP SIZE", String.valueOf(byteCount));
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}
                        });
```

Original image size is 46.32kb(850*566px, .jpg).

but after resize(1200, 500), size is 2400000byte.

why image size was increased??

How to get size(byte) from ImageView using Picasso Library?

Comment: @박민규 what do you want to get new size in bytes ?

Comment: @Charuක I want to get size of Bitmap bitmap in onBitmapLoaded after resizing

Comment: you ve already taken that 2400000 seems correct

Comment: Do you want to get memory image size or the actual file size of the image ?

Comment: @Charuක thanks for your answer!

Comment: @tahsinRupam actual file size of the image

Comment: Images in memory are uncompressed.  jpg files are compressed.  So it will be MUCH bigger in memory. It would be much bigger even if you hadn't resized it but just opened the file.  In memory a image is (for ARGB8888) 4*width*height.  YOur 46kb file woud be 1.9MB in memory

Comment: @박민규 Wrapping the bitmap with a Drawable can be the problem mm thinking

Comment: @Charuක Wrapping it in a drawable will add maybe 100 bytes.  The difference is between a compressed file on disk and an image in memory which must be uncompressed to be displayed.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I think you should add it as an answer those tips are very useful and needs extra time for us to figure out

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your answer